# Angular ngIf causes height CSS transition when toggling between two child components

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a "button" component in Angular, with has a `loading` input. If the value is `false` it displays the text of the button, as displayed via content projection (`<ng-content>`). If `true`, it hides the content and displays a "spinner" component instead.

This done in the template using an `*ngIf`:

```
<button class="btn"
  [ngClass]="{'loading': loading}">
  <ng-content *ngIf="!loading"></ng-content>
  <app-spinner *ngIf="loading"></app-spinner>
</button>
```

This works fine for toggling between the two views; if the Input on the button changes, the template renders it correctly.

However, when the input changes and the spinner is displayed, it causes a strange animation on the height of the button.

This happens when the button CSS has `transition: all 0.25s ease-out;`. If I comment that out, it's fine. But I want to keep the transition property if possible.

I've created a Stackblitz to demonstrate it: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngif-in-button-strange-animation

I am wondering if it's because for split second, both components are in displayed while Angular's change detection is working, but I'm not sure.

Comment: why do you want to keep the transition property? what are you trying to animate on that button? instead of making it "all", only make it the properties you actually want to animate.  The components don't "exist" together, they get swapped, but you've told the browser to take 0.25 seconds to animate out the button, so that's why they're staying together. You could alternatively animate in the loader with a 0,25 second delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your stackblitz and removing the `padding` from the `.btn` class will stop raising the button size.

This is happening because in the first frame, this padding from the `.btn` is being applied, making the button raise it's height. After that, the second style is applied from the `.loading` class, which resets the padding to `padding: 0 12px` and then the height goes to the normal size.